# UIViewPropertyAnimator stops working after presenting another controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11, uiviewpropertyanimator

I use `UIViewPropertyAnimator` for shrinking my view controller’s header:

```
- (UIViewPropertyAnimator *)headerAnimator {
    if (!_headerAnimator) {
        _headerAnimator = [[UIViewPropertyAnimator alloc] initWithDuration:2.f curve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear animations:^{
            self.profileImageBorderWidthConstraint.constant = 58.f;
            self.profileImageBorderHeightConstraint.constant = 58.f;
            self.profileImageBorder.layer.cornerRadius = 29.f;

            self.profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 25.f;

            self.nameLabelTopConstraint.constant = 16.f;

            [self.headerView layoutIfNeeded];
        }];
    }

    return _headerAnimator;
}
```

On scrolling, I set the `fragment`:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat fraction = (scrollView.contentOffset.y / (HeaderHeight-CollapsedHeaderHeight));
    self.headerAnimator.fractionComplete = fraction;
}
```

This works fine. But after I present an another `UIViewController` from this controller and dismiss it, the animator gets in an inactive state and stops responding to the fraction settings. How can I restart it?

What I’ve already tried:

- setting my animator property to `nil`, to let recreate it next time (crashes)
- pausing it on `-viewWillAppear:` to become active (becomes active, but does not animate)
- start it on `-viewWillAppear:` (remains inactive)

Answer (score 4):

So far I found a perfect solution for iOS 11+ and a workaround for earlier OS’s.

iOS 11: You have to set `pausesOnCompletion` to `YES`. This leaves the animation in active state even after the controller is dismissed.

For earlier versions I had to leave `UIViewPropertyAnimator` and create an own function which I where the animation fraction would change and interpolate the values manually:

```
- (void)animateHeaderToScrollPoint {
    // Header
    CGFloat fraction = self.tableView.contentOffset.y / (HeaderHeight-CollapsedHeaderHeight);
    fraction = fminf(fraction, 1.f);
    fraction = fmaxf(fraction, 0.f);
    fraction = 1.f - fraction;

    self.profileImageBorderWidthConstraint.constant = 58.f + (86.f - 58.f) * fraction;
    self.profileImageBorderHeightConstraint.constant = 58.f + (86.f - 58.f) * fraction;
    self.profileImageBorder.layer.cornerRadius = 29.f + (43.f - 29.f) * fraction;

    self.profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 25.f + (39.f - 25.f) * fraction;

    self.nameLabelTopConstraint.constant = 16.f + (31.f - 16.f) * fraction;

    [self.headerView layoutIfNeeded];
}
```